# D3.js: run a transition continuously?

Tags: d3.js, transition

How can I run a transition continuously in D3.js?

For example, say I want to change the `body` colour from red to blue and back again, continuously (I don't, that would be horrendous, but go with it).

This is how I would do it once:

```
d3.select("body").transition().duration(1000).style("background-color", "red");
```

How would I do it continuously?

The closest examples I have seen use `d3.timer`, but I am not sure if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`transition.each()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-each) and the "end" event. The code would look something like the following.

```
function myTrans() {
    d3.select("body").transition().duration(1000).style("background-color", "red")
      .each("end", function() {
        d3.select(this).transition().duration(1000).style("background-color", "blue")
          .each("end", function() { myTrans(); });
      });
}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. Although I'm a bit nervous that it might crash the browser eventually - will it gradually take up more and more memory?

Comment: @Richard this is a recursive function (as it calls itself), so it should throw an error regarding the stack size being exceeded some threshold.

Comment: @SumNeuron It calls itself recursively, but asynchronously, so it will never throw a call stack size error.

Answer (score 1):

For D3 version 4 you have to use .on instead of .each (based on Lars answer):

```
function myTrans() {
    d3.select("body").transition().duration(1000).style("background-color", "red")
      .on("end", function() {
        d3.select(this).transition().duration(1000).style("background-color", "blue")
          .on("end", function() { myTrans(); });
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and I used **css animations** to solve the problem. With simple html and css would be like this:

```css
#cube {
  width: 120px; 
  height:120px;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: transcolor;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  }


@keyframes transcolor {
  from {
    background-color:#535455;
  }
  
  to {
   background-color:#bf2c23;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="cube">

</div>
```

With d3 and javascript :

```js
d3.select("body")
  .style("animation", "transcolor 3s infinite linear alternate");
```

```css
@keyframes transcolor {
  from {
    background-color:#535455;
  }
  
  to {
   background-color:#bf2c23;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```