# D3 JS - Force Graph - Animate nodes individually

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Apologies for the question - I know similar questions have been asked - but I cannot find a solution for my particular problem.

JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/TheDarkne55/tmkbLk4b/2/

That's the basic FD graph example, slightly modified and with my code added :

```
    /* --- MY CODE START --- */     
var intervalID = setInterval(animationTick, 1000);

function animationTick() {

    var randomInt = Number(getRandomInt(0, 5));
    var currentRadius = Number(node.attr("r"));
    var newRadius = Number(currentRadius + randomInt);

    node.attr("r", function (d) {return currentRadius + randomInt;});   
}
/* --- MY CODE END --- */
```

**What I've got:**
My real example is a lot more complex, which is not important for this question.
This is just a simple graph.
I've added an animationTick() function so that I can control how often its called.

**What I want:**
I want the circles to be animated as I require (Grow-and-Shrink) forever.
(in this Fiddle I've just added the "grow" part)
The simple algorithm in this example just tries to add a random int to the **current** radius.
So, with each Node/circle starting off with different radii, I expect them to remain different-sized when they're being incremented by the same amount. But instead they become the same size.

The Problem:
1. I'm new to D3 JS and don't understand very well how iteration of d3 elements works, in different ways
2. In this example, as you'll see on the first trigger, instead of all *increasing* their **current** radius by a relative amount, they all become the **same** size, and then continue in that way

I'm sure its just a matter of properly iterating through the nodes or node-data, and I've tried manipulating those directly as well, but I've been stumped for a while now.

Any pointers in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886834/increase-and-decrease-radius-of-a-circle-using-d3-transition

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127805/d3-js-run-a-transition-continuously

Comment: That sorted me out - you, sir, are a legend ! I knew it was something small I needed to do, but my brain stopped working 2 days ago. Thanks a lot - I owe you a beer ! :)

Comment: Silly question, but how can I mark this as answered ? Or is that not possible without a separate post ?

Comment: You can add an answer explaining what you did to solve the problem or simply delete the question.

Comment: Oh or if it's a duplicate of one of the questions I've linked to, let me know and I'll close it as such.

Comment: Hi Lars. Yes, the first link was the one that solved my problem, which was figuring out how to iterate and change nodes based on an input dataset. Please close this, with that as the reference. Thanks a lot!